# wordpress wp_insert_post removing inline display block

Tags: php, wordpress

Company is currently moving from an inhouse CMS into a Wordpress structure, I've been taking care of the script that will be in charge of moving pages into WP. Everything is going well but an issue importing images is happening that I'm not sure what is breaking it. For example an image that is:

When it goes through the function wp_insert_post it becomes:

So the *display: block* code is actually getting removed. I've been doing some debugging and the data that gets sent to the *wp_insert_post* function does actually have the *display: block;* while if I grab the post content right after the write function goes through *display: block* is completely gone.

So sadly my Wordpress knowledge as been improving but sadly I'm just not getting much luck figuring what the issue is with these devices.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you write some extra CSS for this?

Comment: The inline style of the images is not the same for every single image that is already set in the inhouse CMS, it's also not doable go through each of the content pages giving the images some css class to handle it through a stylesheet. I just want to understand why wordpress wp_insert_post function is removing the display: block only, as it doesn't touch the other inline style rules